# Why Is Asserting Resolved UIColor Failing After Changing UIUserInterfaceStyle in Unit Test?

Tags: uikit

I am working on a project that uses named color assets, and I am responsible for updating the unit tests that assert the correct color values.

We have an `XCTestCase` subclass (`BaseXCTestCase`) that has a `window` property, which is set to a value of `UIApplication.shared.firstKeyWindow`:

```
var window = UIApplication.shared.firstKeyWindow!
```

`firstKeyWindow` is defined as `windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first` in an `UIApplication` extension:

```
var firstKeyWindow: UIWindow? {
    return windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first
}
```

Additionally, there are two properties used for accessing `window`'s `traitCollection` and `userInterfaceStyle`:

```
var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
    return window.traitCollection
}

var userInterfaceStyle: UIUserInterfaceStyle {
    get {
        return window.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle
    }
    set {
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = newValue
    }
}
```

The class that contains the color tests inherits from `BaseXCTestCase`. Then, our tests are configured as:

```
func testColor() {
  var subject = .namedColor

  /// Light mode
  userInterfaceStyle = .light
  subject = subject.resolvedColor(with: traitCollection)
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.hexString(), "#ABC123")
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.alpha, 1.0)

  /// Dark mode
  userInterfaceStyle = .dark
  subject = subject.resolvedColor(with: traitCollection)
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.hexString(), "#BCD234")
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.alpha, 1.0)
```

}

The first two assertions of the test succeed when asserting the color for light mode. However, the assertions for the dark mode color fail, and the failure messages indicate that the light mode color and alpha values are persisting.

I set a breakpoint at the final light-mode assertion, and printing `traitCollection` provides me with the following output, which I expect:

```
<UITraitCollection: 0x60000198a760; 
  UserInterfaceIdiom = Phone, 
  DisplayScale = 3, 
  DisplayGamut = P3, 
  HorizontalSizeClass = Compact, 
  VerticalSizeClass = Regular,
  UserInterfaceStyle = Light, 
  UserInterfaceLayoutDirection = LTR, 
  ForceTouchCapability = Unavailable,
  PreferredContentSizeCategory = L, 
  AccessibilityContrast = Normal, 
  UserInterfaceLevel = Base
>
```

In the printed output, I see `UserInterfaceStyle = Light`.

Then, I set a breakpoint at the final dark-mode assertion, and printing `traitCollection` provides me with the following output, which I expect:

```
<UITraitCollection: 0x600001990460; 
  UserInterfaceIdiom = Phone, 
  DisplayScale = 3, 
  DisplayGamut = P3, 
  HorizontalSizeClass = Compact, 
  VerticalSizeClass = Regular, 
  UserInterfaceStyle = Dark, 
  UserInterfaceLayoutDirection = LTR, 
  ForceTouchCapability = Unavailable, 
  PreferredContentSizeCategory = L, 
  AccessibilityContrast = Normal, 
  UserInterfaceLevel = Base
>
```

This time, I see `UserInterfaceStyle = Dark`, which I expect.

If I remove the code that sets the interface style to light and sets the resolved color, then the test passes:

```
func testColor() {
  var subject = .namedColor

  /// Light mode
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.hexString(), "#ABC123")
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.alpha, 1.0)

  /// Dark mode
  userInterfaceStyle = .dark
  subject = subject.resolvedColor(with: traitCollection)
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.hexString(), "#BCD234")
  XCTAssertEqual(subject.alpha, 1.0)
```

}

My question is then, why are the assertions for the dark-mode color and alpha values failing? Specifically, what is causing the color to not be resolved after overriding `window`'s `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`?

Shouldn't the following code cause the color to be resolved with the trait collection that contains `UserInterfaceStyle = Dark` as the dark-mode color and alpha values?

```
userInterfaceStyle = .dark
subject = subject.resolvedColor(with: traitCollection)
```

If I move the dark-mode logic above the light-mode logic, then the light-mode assertions fail. I don't know what I am failing to do between the first assertions and second assertions to ensure the user interface style is being respected.

Comment: Initial thought: is this a main thread issue? Not sure if unit tests are guaranteed to happen on the main thread...

Comment: Even though the question has already been answered, I'm wondering if you considered just instantiating trait collections with a `UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle:)` initializer instead of manipulating the window's trait collection. That would provide better isolation from the environment for your tests.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev I had not considered that until now. I updated our test suite to instantiate trait collections via `UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle:)`. As you stated, I think it provides better isolation from our test environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think unit tests are guaranteed to run on the main thread, so maybe try a `DispatchQueue.main.async` for the UI update and see how that goes.

Comment: I wrapped the assertions in a dispatch to the main queue, and that resolved the failures. I thought that trait collection updates happen on the main thread, but I suppose I overlooked the fact that unit tests aren't guaranteed to run on the main thread.